# How to delete string when its randomly chosen javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

My code randomly chooses a string and writes it on the screen with javascript. This might be a little confusing but i want to know if its possible to make it so when it randomly chooses a string and writes it on the page it also deletes that string from the code so it can never be chosen again? Heres my code

```
    KeywordArray = new Array(7);  
    KeywordArray[0] = "apple";  
    KeywordArray[1] = "pear";  
    KeywordArray[2] = "orange";  
    KeywordArray[3] = "banana";  
    KeywordArray[4] = "stawberry"; 
    randno = Math.floor ( Math.random() * KeywordArray.length );
```

Then at the bottom of my html page I have

```
    <script>document.write(KeywordArray[randno]);</script>
```

I want to know if its possible to make it so when apple is randomly chosen and put on the screen it deletes it from the array so nobody else can ever get the word apple? Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: No, it's not possible without server-side code.

Comment: When you reload the page the JavaScript array is defined again and initialized with the same data. To make your request possible for multiple users you have to store array values in the database at the server side, pass one random value to the client, and remove it from the database when page is rendered.

Comment: Keeping used words, just marking them used, might be helpful. Prevent duplicates if you ever update the list etc.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want to store some information server-side, but javascript is client-side so it isn't the best choice. Try Php if your server supports it.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = KeywordArray.indexOf("apple");
KeywordArray.splice(index, 1);
```

But of course the above works on the client side.

Comment: Indeed this doesn't address the "nobody else can ever get the word" part of the question.

Comment: The "nobody else" does not fit your code, which is client side. Try using php are some other server side code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```
document.write(KeywordArray.splice(randno,1));
```

**note**

If you would like to store what is already used even if the page reloads, you can use localStorage. That will save the elements that have already been show. (However It will be shown to other people, to prevent this you might want to use some Server side code eg. PHP)

So then you will need to use

```
localStorage.setItem("used"+randno, "true");
```

And check if `localStorage.setItem("used"+randno) == "true"`, if this is so yo will need to make an other random numer (with a while loop).

Be shure that you vane enoug elments then because if all your elments have been shown, you will run into an infinite loop

You must also be aware of the fact that localstorage is not suported by certain browsers. If you want to know more I recomend you to read the [spec's](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) on it

Comment: This is useful to have one user get a different word each time. But different users still share the same initial list list of words and will often get the same word (localStorage is private for one user, as it is client-side)